# How to make copied files respect ACL settings?

Tags: permissions, file-copy, acl

Say I open in a PDF file with permissions `600` in a graphical application. I want to "save as" it in a folder with ACL settings as follows:

```
$ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: doron
# group: myOffice
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
group:myOffice:rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:group::rwx
default:group:myOffice:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

And I want the PDF file to get `660` permissions when it reaches that folder. However, the file retains the `600` permissions it had in the original location.

It seems that because the file wasn't created at that directory, but only copied there, the ACL permissions don't apply. Is my observation correct? I want to overcome this behavior.